# How do I customize cards in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular-material cards and I am trying to customize it. Most of the things I am able to do, but I am not able to set the height of cards. 
Suppose I want to make a card having height of 30px only. How can I achieve that? If I am using only a A tag in it's content. How do I set the padding-top bottom n it.

```
 <md-card class="numb">
  <md-card-content>
  <a href="">Sourabh garg<span>7415326288</span>
   <span>Sourabhxxx@gmail.com</span></a>
  </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
```

My css

```
  md-card{
  padding:0px;
  min-height:30px;
  margin-left:300px;
  width: 800px;
  md-card-content a {
   color:black;
   text-decoration:none;
    span{
   padding-left: 100px;
   }
 }}
```

Please tell me What I am missing. :(

Comment: inspect it in your browser and see what styles are being applied

Comment: Ah! Yes. Had completely forgotten about that. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
min-height:30px !important
```

for important into css to must apply/override